# Why does -contains not seem to work with AD security permissions PSCustomObjects

Tags: powershell, azure-active-directory

I am trying to make a list of job titles and their security permissions. I would love to have two lists, a list of security permissions that are shared with more than one member with that title, and permissions that are outliers so that we can better make templates for new hires with certain job roles. I am using -contains to match security permissions with recurring security permissions but it always returns false. I am guessing that each security permission has some unique value to it per user, but even when I try to just match something like the name, it doesn't work

Here is my code.

```
#get all the users with a title and group them by title
$Titles = Get-ADUser -Filter * -Properties Title | Where-Object Title | Sort-Object Title | Group-Object Title
#loop through each group
foreach ($Title in $Titles){
        #zero out outliers and shared permissions
        $OutlierPermissions = @()
        $SharedPermissions = @()
        #loop through each user in each group
        foreach ($User in $Title.Group){
                $Permissions = @()
                #get all the permissions of the user
                $Permissions = Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership $User | Sort-Object Name
                #loop through each permission
                foreach ($Permission in $Permissions){
                        #if this permission is shared by more than one user
                        if($OutlierPermissions -contains $Permission){
                                #and not already added
                                if($SharedPermissions -notcontains $Permission){
                                        $SharedPermissions += $Permission
                                }
                        #else add to list of outliers
                        }else{$OutlierPermissions += $Permission}
                }
        }
}
```

I have also tried

```
-contains $Permission.Name

$Permissions = Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership $User | Sort-Object Name | Select Name
```

anything to get some part of redundancy to the security permission
is there a way around this?

Comment: So you want to group all titles and for each title have their associated groups, if so the way you're approaching your code seems over complicated and you dont need 2 collections you just need 1 hashtable

Comment: Yes you are right, I turned it into a hashtable and skipped all that -contains nonsense

Answer (score 1):

To put it simple `$OutlierPermissions -contains $Permission` will never work because `$Permission` is an instance of [`ADGroup`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.activedirectory.management.adgroup?view=activedirectory-management-10.0) and `$OutlierPermissions` is a collection of `ADGroup` instances and these objects are not [comparable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.icomparable?view=net-7.0) or [equatable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.iequatable-1?view=net-7.0) so `-contains` will always return `$false`. Instead what you want to do if pick one property of these objects that has such capabilities to have a proper comparison, in example, you can use the [`.ObjectGUID` property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.activedirectory.management.adobject.objectguid?view=activedirectory-management-10.0#microsoft-activedirectory-management-adobject-objectguid).

If I'm understanding your code correctly, it could be simplified to this logic:

```
$map = @{}
# get all the users with the `Title` populated
foreach($user in Get-ADUser -LDAPFilter "(title=*)" -Properties Title) {
    # if this `Title` has not yet been added to the hash
    if(-not $map.ContainsKey($user.Title)) {
        # use a `List<T>` for dynamic additions of new groups
        # and a `HasShet<T>` to not duplicate additions
        $map[$user.Title] = @{
            ProcessedMembership = [System.Collections.Generic.HashSet[guid]]::new()
            Membership = [System.Collections.Generic.List[object]]::new()
        }
    }
    # for each group this user is a member of
    foreach($group in Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership $user) {
        # if this group has not yet already been added
        if(-not $map[$user.Title]['ProcessedMembership'].Add($group.ObjectGUID)) {
            # add this group to the `Membership` List for this `Title`
            $map[$user.Title]['Membership'].Add($group)
        }
    }
}
```

Using a [`Hashtable`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_hash_tables?view=powershell-7.2) to gather all results where the `Keys` are the unique `Titles` and the `Values` is a nested `Hashtable` consisting of groups already processed `ProcessedMembership` (this keeps track of duplicates using a [`HashSet<T>`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.hashset-1?view=net-6.0)) and a [`List<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1?view=net-7.0) where you can keep a reference of all groups objects associated with each `Title`.